# Why is CORS reporting my HTTP status is not ok?

Tags: javascript, api, cors

I'm using https://add0n.com/access-control.html in order to bypass the CORS policy for an extension I'm making, however, I'm receiving this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myexampleapi.com/' from origin 'https://www.somedomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

This is the code I'm using to access the API is:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", 'https://api.example.com/test/getstats?userId=76561399568194663', true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("ApiKey", "13cf02fb-fake-442f-f7cc-9ee44g48748b");
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(xmlHttp.responseText)
    }
}
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

This error is ONLY occurring in Chrome and Firefox has no problems. I've been looking for 8 hours now and am getting desperate. Any advise on solving this?

Comment: what is the response status for the OPTIONS preflight request?

Comment: It says the HTTP response status is 0

Comment: if you don't control the server, you need to set up a server to act as a proxy, you can't get around cors otherwise. if you do control the server, you need to set your cors headers properly.

Comment: @Syllith - well, that's the issue, `0` is not between `200` and `299`

Comment: But why is it returning 0? Firefox is not having this issue and I've been bypassing CORS at multiple points throughout my project with no issue. I'm having a hard time understanding what is different with this one

Comment: do all your other requests trigger CORS preflight?

Comment: that question is unanswerable without knowing exactly what you've been doing to "bypass CORS at multiple points" and exactly what you're trying to do now.

Comment: to be honest, I thought a well written extension has no CORS issues to bypass

Comment: No other XHR requests are triggering CORS preflight. My guess is that the reason this one is different is because I'm adding a custom header to it. The other ones take the token in a query string. The only other time I'm adding my own header is through a same-origin domain, which explains why it isn't throwing an error. I have to make these calls because I need to get data that's only available through 3rd party websites

Comment: CORS also restricts what headers you can send. The preflight request determines this. If the API server isn't set up to specifically allow `ApiKey` as a header, your request won't work. APIs aren't always intended to be consumed directly from a page. Often you need to set up your own server that can proxy the requests, cache the responses, and keep the API key secure.

Comment: I might just try to do that. I have a server I can do this from, but I'm still not understanding why Firefox is working. I assume it's because it's handling the CORS bypass script I inserted differently than Chrome, but it's frustrating I can't bypass it the same way

Comment: You might check out [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers). See if the preflight response has that header and allows `ApiKey`. (Also, I wonder if [this](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) has anything to do with your issue.)

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution. I ended up setting up a proxy server using PHP that uses CURL to call the API for me. This way, I would need to pass a custom header that was preventing me from bypassing CORS on Chrome. It works like a charm, but I was really hoping not to have to do this, so if anyone has any better ideas, let me know.